# FastText: Can't get cross_validation

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, gensim

I am struggling to implement FastText ([FTTransformer](https://github.com/kataev/gensim/blob/969b7178a7c90690f18db33807b390048ef0c83e/gensim/sklearn_api/ftmodel.py)) into a Pipeline that iterates over different vectorizers. More particular, I can't get cross-validation scores. Following code is used:

```
%%time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.sklearn_api.ftmodel import FTTransformer
np.random.seed(0)

data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/dqKFZ12m')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.text, data.label, random_state=0)
w2v_texts = [simple_preprocess(doc) for doc in X_train]

models = [FTTransformer(size=10, min_count=0, seed=42)]
classifiers = [LogisticRegression(random_state=0)]

for model in models:

    for classifier in classifiers:

        model.fit(w2v_texts)
        classifier.fit(model.transform(X_train), y_train)

        pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('vec', model),
                ('clf', classifier)
            ])

        print(pipeline.score(X_train, y_train))
        #print(model.gensim_model.wv.most_similar('kirk'))

        cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
```

> KeyError: 'all ngrams for word  "Machine learning can be useful
>   branding sometimes" absent from model'

**How can the problem be solved?**

Sidenote: My other pipelines with `D2VTransformer` or `TfIdfVectorizer` work just fine. Here, I can simply apply `pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)` after defining the pipeline, instead of the two fits as shown above. It seems like [FTTransformer](https://github.com/kataev/gensim/blob/969b7178a7c90690f18db33807b390048ef0c83e/gensim/sklearn_api/ftmodel.py) doesn't integrate so well with other given vectorizers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to be used in a pipeline, `FTTransformer` needs to be modified to split documents to words inside its `fit` method. One can do it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.sklearn_api.ftmodel import FTTransformer
np.random.seed(0)


class FTTransformer2(FTTransformer):

    def fit(self, x, y):
        super().fit([simple_preprocess(doc) for doc in x])
        return self


data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/dqKFZ12m')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.text, data.label, random_state=0)

classifiers = [LogisticRegression(random_state=0)]

for classifier in classifiers:

    pipeline = Pipeline([
            ('ftt', FTTransformer2(size=10, min_count=0, seed=0)),
            ('clf', classifier)
        ])

    score = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
    print(score)
```

Comment: That seems to work. Thank you! One last question: What if all data is prepared like: `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split([simple_preprocess(doc) for doc in data.text], data.label, random_state=0)`? The other classifiers, such as D2VTransformer, needed such input. So I wonder how I can tell FTTransformer to use the unprocessed data (which seems odd because processed data is lemmatized etc.). If I prepare the data like above, the classifiers won't work anymore.

Comment: This doesn't work because the `transform` method of FTTransformer expects documents that are not split into words.

Comment: I see... So basically I can't lemmatize either, because the fit model does not correspond to the loaded data?

Comment: You can probably write a similar custom method for `transform` that accepts tokenized documents, and then you could pre-tokenize (and lemmatize if needed) the texts before inputting them into `train_test_split`. But FastText is meant to work on the subword level, so lemmatization should be redundant alongside FastText.

Comment: I think I'll try an extra post on that. I need to have a D2V, FT and CV in one pipeline iteration.